# Get subdomains from source cod

Tags: linux, bash

I have source code of a website and I try to get subdomains from code with using linux command. I try to use **grep "*.website.com"** but it gets me just "website.com"

So what should I do, could you please help me?

Comment: try `grep website.com`

Comment: What do you mean by "source code of a website"? Is this the actual _web application_ source code (e.g, PHP files), or just an HTML page you downloaded?

Comment: I have HTML code and it contains  **<a href="http://dev.website.com/" target="_blank">** etc. I just wanna get **dev.website.com** etc.

Comment: `grep -Po '[\w.]*website.com' file.html`